# Flask cookie not set with ajax request

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, cookies, flask

I'm trying to set a cookie from a Flask server on an ajax request from a react app. I made an easy test case and even then, the cookie is sent in the response, but isn't set in the browser

Flask:

```
@app.route('/is_alive', methods = ['POST'])
def alive():
    resp = app.make_response("There should be a cookie")
    resp.set_cookie("testing", 'testing')
    return resp
```

Javascript:

```
static isAlivePost() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                firstParam: 'true'
            })
        }

        fetch(endpoints.MOCK_API + 'is_alive', options)
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response.text());
            }).then(function(data) {
                resolve(data);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                reject(e);
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `credentials: 'same-origin'` needed to be `credentials: 'include'`.